# Angular receiving blank data, but data is not blank

Tags: angular

I don't really know how to ask this question or what is happening.

I am doing an API call to get data, like such:

```
getSingleGroupStats(uuid:string, req:any){
  return this.http.get(`${this.resourceUrl}/${uuid}/endpoint`, {
    params: req,
    observe: 'response',
  })
}
```

All my API calls look like this.  Now when logging the data body in my component, I get this really weird response:

[image]

So it seems that there are 2 objects in my array, but when expanding the array... no data.

When looking on the network tab of my browser, there is actually data in the array.  So I do not know what is going on.  This causes errors like:

```
cannot read property whatever of undefined
```

because the component cannot see the data.

I don't know what to do or what is happening.

**EDIT**

I am actually subscribing to the response inside my component, like such:

```
this.service.getSingleGroupStats('1234', {}).subscribe(
  (res:HttpResponse<any>) => { 
    console.log('single stats -> ', res.body)
  }
)
```

This `console.log` is where the data is all wonky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're observing for 'response', you're getting the whole response with headers and body.  It return an Observable of typed HttpResponse rather than just the JSON data. As stated in docs, you can just do response.body to access the data.

https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: ag really...
Thanks for the assist.